# Understand the `call` opcode in this contract

Tags: contract-invocation, security, reentrant-attacks

Hello, I am posting a quick question regarding the functionality this contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/6b63ea3612dde97082aab468157950f927618d31#code
From the source code, I am not even able to find a `call` (`send`, `transfer`, and so on) statement.

But to my surprise, this contract seems to have plenty of call opcode in its opcode sequence. Actually I tried one smart contract bug detector and the detector treats this contract as under "re-entrancy attack".

Could anyone shed some lights on the mismatch here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What tool did you use? The only suspicious thing there is suicide/selfdestruct if you can overwrite the owner of the contract.

Comment: @Ismael Right. I am using `JEB3` for decompilation and a homemade script. Somehow it marks this `suicide` issue as well. But my question is how come this contract can have a `call`? I just cannot find an external call in its source code. Does it make any sense to you..?

Comment: Using this online decompiler [Smart Contract Guardian](https://www.trustlook.com/products/smartcontractguardian) the only calls I see are to precompiled contracts, and that should not be an issue.